# Django-allauth + reactjs+ linkedin login redirect uri issue + Not enough permissions to access: GET /me

Tags: django-rest-framework, python-3.6, django-allauth

I am using `drf` + `ReactJs` to do social login am able to integrate google login and facebook login using `django allauth` package , but when I tried to integrate linkedin login getting error :

> invalid redirect uri

TO be more precise am getting this error

```
allauth.socialaccount.providers.oauth2.client.OAuth2Error: Error retrieving access token: b'{"error":"invalid_redirect_uri","error_description":"Unable to retrieve access token: appid/redirect uri/code verifier does not match authorization code. Or authorization code expired. Or external member binding exists"}
```

----few updates after tying out few fixes -----

1. Tried fetching the access token from backend and login the user using a seprate api it showed the redirect uri issue.
2. Tried directly calling the linkedin token url from postman and now I get Invalid request error.

**First method worked after few tryouts but now getting incorrect value error.**

**Tried fetching code with scope as r_liteprofile but now getting 403 forbidden**

```
{'serviceErrorCode': 100, 'message': 'Not enough permissions to access: GET /me', 'status': 403}
```

I tried changing url to backend and frontend both showing same error. Can anyone get me how to fix this issue ?

I am not sure what all additional details needed for sorting this out, Please let me know if any needed.

Answer (score 0):

Finally able to find the solution

the issue was with the code generated from the sdk used to implement linkedin login in reactjs, which has only scope

```
 r_emailaddress
r_liteprofile
```

Adding additional scope

```
w_member_social
```

And regarding redirect uri issue

we are suppose to use the same redirect uri in both frontend and backend
made things working , posting this here since it will help someone in future facing same problem.

thank you all

Comment: Can you please help us. we are getting same issue while using DRF + reactjs with linkedin.  our domain for backend is different then frontend So how to manage it ? which redirect url should we use ?